# VPN client sees LAN computers but cannot connect to Internet via VPN

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I'm using Windows 7's "Allow incomming connections" to setup a VPN "server".

My laptop connects to the VPN server and I can access the LAN inside the VPN. But no traffic is routed to the internet, the result I want is this:

Laptop -> VPN tunnel over (insecure) Internet -> LAN -> Internet. Currently I have setup a HTTP proxy on a LAN computer and set the laptop to use this proxy server to connect to the internet, like browsing. I had to setup the DNS for the laptop vpn to  the DNS used on the LAN for resolving things, but doing a tracert on 8.8.8.8 or any other ip doesnt work. So all traffic is routed via the VPN but it's stopped somewhere. Status on the WAN Miniport PPTP says on IPv4 connectivity - Not Connected.

I'm not very experienced with VPN tech, but I'm traveling to a country I don't trust internet-wise. And I'm bringing a laptop with me. I just need an encrypted tunnel that transparently transmits data over the unsafe internet via an encrypted tunnel to my home network, and then back out unencrypted. This is what is not working without the proxy server (which is only a HTTP proxy).

The VPN server is a VM (Virtual Machine) with 2 NIC adapters, the host also has 2 NIC adapters, so NIC0 goes through LAN behind a router from ISP0 and NIC1 is on a router from ISP1 that gives a public IP (the other creates a LAN, with a single public IP).

That I can access my LAN using VPN is just a bonus. I do not want to purchase software to make this work.

Sorry if this question is confusing, it was difficult to find the proper terms.

Comment: OpenVPN is free and open source, and is highly recommended because it doesn't use IPSec (which is more complicated) and it doesn't require any proxy servers -- no matter which VPN you set up for yourself, you will need to have at least some basic technical knowledge about **VPNs**, **firewalls**, Windows **services** (because you're using the Windows OS), and **network routing**:  http://www.openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/overview.html

Comment: If you are currently using a VPN (you seemed to be hinting that you'd like a suggestion, which is why I referenced OpenVPN), which one are you currently trying to use?

Comment: Basically I followed this recipe: http://www.pcworld.com/article/210562/how_to_set_up_vpn_in_windows_7.html Which works, except I had to add the DNS server to the LAN router. It just doesnt forward internet traffic via the tunnel to the LAN and out on the internet again. I'm not sure how to describe this. I know firewalls, setting up NATs etc. It's just the VPN part I'm on rocky grounds. I'll look at OpenVPN. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That's the one the comes included with Windows.  I've had to switch many clients over to OpenVPN (or Cisco's commercial offerings) to resolve weird routing problems like that.  OpenVPN has a configuration option that does exactly what you need:  http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect

Comment: I'll try it out and see how it works. Do you have any experience about OpenVPN will work the same way with an iPhone (3GS)? The proxy-server I'm doing now works for basic surfing but not for Twitter or other apps that don't like VPN/Proxy.

Comment: Many years later and this still the top result in Google.  I too followed the instructions on pcworld, and similar ones elsewhere - none explaining how to get all traffic (including internet traffic) to flow via the VPN.  Anyway I could not access internet once on VPN, but thought I'd do a TRACERT 8.8.8.8 to see.  The packets were getting through to 8.8.8.8 (some timeouts on intermediate steps but no worries) - so actually it was just a DNS issue.  Go into IP4 properties manually set DNS to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and away we go!